# Accessing REST service after login within browser using oauth2 and spring security using java config

Tags: rest, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-java-config

I have implemented Oauth2 using sparkl2 app. I am using spring-security as described in the sparkl2 app using java config. I can successfully get auth token using curl and i can invoke web service using curl.

My question is

How I can access my REST service within the same browser after login into my application? I am not sure what I am missing here?

Let me elaborate my question in more details. The way browser keep session after login and we can access any protected resource in the application, what is the best way to implement so that I can test my REST api from browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spring security keeps it in session. Session id is stored in browser cookie, so its passed with each request to your service. Then spring security should take it and check if specific session(with user logged in) is allowed to hit this particular url.

I would start with configuring secure paths in your java config:

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers().hasAnyRole(...)
```

or some other method instead antMatchers.

you probably have to log in user into spring security on some oauth callback, something like:

```
Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, authorities);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. As I explained earlier that I used sparkl2 code and changed in-memory tokenStore to jdbcTokenStore but I was still using in-memory token store in http filter like http.inMemory()... so I fixed this now when I try to get auth token using curl I am not getting auth token anymore I can see that UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter is not invoked when I do curl but when I try to login through login form in my application I am successfully authenticated. What I am missing here? Looks like now there are two problems :)

Comment: are you sure you send POST using curl?

Comment: Yes I am sure that I am doing POST in curl, the auxiliary issue is resolved that I mentioned above in my first comment. The primary issue remain as is.